# Google Apps Script, how to monitor account activity without G Suite plan

Tags: google-apps-script, google-account

I was wondering how I can monitor account activity without having a G Suite Plan. I tried singing up but my apparently not so trusty .tk domain was denied. I then tried the following code and triggered it every minute to see if anything changes when I log out and in from different devices, it did not.

```
  function testt() {

      var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
      var eins = Session.getActiveUser()
      var zwei = Session.getActiveUserLocale()
      var drei = Session.getEffectiveUser()
      var vier = Session.getScriptTimeZone()
      var funf = Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey()

      MailApp.sendEmail({
          to: "mymail@provider.com",
          subject: "Backup Session Monitor",
          htmlBody: 'email is: ' + email + '<br>' + 'getActiveUser() ' + eins          + '<br>' + 'getActiveUserLocale() ' + zwei + '<br>' + 'getEffectiveUser() ' + drei + '<br>' + 'getScriptTimeZone() ' + vier + '<br>' + 'getTemporaryActiveUserKey() ' + funf
  });

}
```

I set up a backup email address though and receive notice when a new device logs in into the account.

I use this account to receive backups and the login is secured with a simple password without 2 factor auth, to provide compatibility with the backup script I run. I could do 2 factor auth and use an apps password, but you can still use that to login, so I dont see the benefit.

Comment: What "activity" are you trying to monitor? Emails? Log ins? Please be more specific.

Comment: log ins, but I choose to rely on the standard google alert via email when someone logs in